# "select list inconsistent with GROUP BY" when using MAX function

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, max

I don't get why this one doesn't work :

```
SELECT stat1, max(stat2)
FROM games
WHERE stat3= x;
```

But that does:

```
SELECT max(stat2)
FROM games
WHERE stat3= x;
```

im new with sql and functions so i don't understand that well what that error wants to indicate or fix..
(I get the error "select list inconsistent with GROUP BY ; amend GROUP BY clause to stat1")

Answer (score 4):

Please research how to use aggregate functions in sql. The first query should have a group by. Tag the appropriate database to further assist you.

```
SELECT stat1, 
       max(stat2) AS MaxStat2
  FROM games
 WHERE stat3= x
 GROUP BY stat1;
```

Comment: i was working in sql developer for Oracle's database

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT stat1 FROM ..` by itself means to return the individual values of `stat1` for all matching rows.  It will produce one output row for each row selected by the WHERE clause.

`SELECT max(stat2) FROM ..` by itself means to find the maximum value of `stat2` over all matching rows.  It will produce a single output row, regardless of how many input rows are processed by the query.

`SELECT stat1, max(stat2) FROM ..` is apparently inconsistent.  The first expression implies that we want many rows.  The second expression implies that we want one row.

If you add `GROUP BY stat1` to the query, that resolves the inconsistency.  It indicates that the input rows should be grouped together by the value of `stat1`, and that `max(stat2)` should be calculated independently for each of those groups.

Comment: your explanation helped a lot to understand what caused the error. Putting GROUP BY ```stat1``` it will give all ```stat1``` column from all rows selected by the WHERE clause. 
I want to take the maximum from column ```stat2``` and show ```stat1``` row. So i want only one row as a result. The row that has maximum column ```stat2``` and show also the column ```stat1``` . I don't know if you understand me.

Answer (score 2):

Every non-aggregated expression in the `select` clause must appear in the `group by` clause.

The second query has just one expression in the `select` clause, which is an aggregation function - so no `group by` clause is needed. This gives you the maximum value of `stat2` for rows where `stat3` matches the parameter.

The first query has a non-aggregate expression in the `select` clause (`stat1`) and no `group by` clause, which makes it invalid SQL. If you want the maximum `stat2` *per distinct value of `stat1`, then add a `group by` clause to the query:

```
SELECT stat1, max(stat2) FROM games WHERE stat3= x GROUP BY stat1;
```

On the other hand, if you want to know what is the value of `stat1` for which `stat2` reaches its max value, then it is different; this is called a *greatest-n-per-group* problem, and you can solve it by filtering rather than aggregating, as:

```
select g.*
from games g
where 
    g.stat3 = :x
    and g.stat2 = (select max(g1.stat2) from games g1 where g1.stat3 = :x)
```

Comment: i think i want the second of what you say. i want the to show up the column ```stat1``` of the maximum of all rows for column ```stat2```. I will try your answer and come back with results and a response. Thanks